# Remove and later re-add all event handlers associated with a groupbox in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to get the collection of handlers associated with a groupbox in C# winforms?

For the cases the checked statuses need to be changed programatically (not by the user), I need to turn off the handlers so other parts of the program do not fire. It is tedious to do this by hand for many handlers.

Is there a working code version of this pseudocode that does not work below?

```
foreach(Control C in parent.groupBox1.Controls)
            {
                C.disableHandlers()
            }
//change controls handlers would have interfered with
foreach(Control C in parent.groupBox1.Controls)
            {
                C.enableHandlers()
            }
```

Comment: I don't think so...but you can add a state variable that the code in your event handlers can check before processing.

Comment: I take it back, there is an example of how someone did this here, but it's not trivial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/623579/Temporarily-disable-event-handler

Comment: I like the state variable solution. That's pretty clever. I don't like the huge solution at your link. What I ended up doing is actually the same as at the bottom of the link: checkbox.checkedchanged -= eventhandler; code; checkbox.checkedchanged += eventhandler

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use some crazy reflection code to do this, but you don't want to do that because you'll invariably run into "well I still want to keep this event just not the others".

I recommend making a class that contains a list of add-listener delegates and a list of remove-listener delegates, and then iterate through and execute each delegate at the appropriate times.